# Could I Test CAN Tranceiver with External Loopback Mode?

Tags: can-bus

Hello I am using STM32H753 over a custom PCB.
I have no any CAN Analyzer except oscilloscope, multimeter and logic analyzer.
We have a problem with CAN BUS communication.
I am suspecting of CAN Tranceiver but we couldn't find the root cause yet.

There are external and internal loopback modes in STM32H7 to test CAN, However these modes also allow us to see the messages what we sent on CAN TX.
I have two different product which has different STM32H753 variant. One is working and the other one is not. Their tranceivers are different but almost same pinout and behavior.

My assumption was if I see my messages on CAN TX then I have to see them CAN H and CAN L.
I wrote test code.
I tried both test code in both device.

On working one, I saw messages on CAN Tx and also see messages with in a suppress way which I thought because of no termination resistor at the end.

On the not-working one, I also saw messages at CAN TX and there is no any move at CAN H or CAN L.

My question is my test was is true or still I could miss something or this test does not imply anyhting ?

```
  HAL_Delay(100);
  if(HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxBuffer(&hfdcan1, &TxHeader, TxData_Node1_To_Node2, FDCAN_TX_BUFFER0    ) != HAL_OK)
  {
      Error_Handler();
  }
  /* Send Tx buffer message */
  if(HAL_FDCAN_EnableTxBufferRequest(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_TX_BUFFER0) != HAL_OK)
  {
      Error_Handler();
  }
  while(HAL_FDCAN_IsTxBufferMessagePending(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_TX_BUFFER0) == 1);

  /* Polling for reception complete on buffer index 0 */
  while(HAL_FDCAN_IsRxBufferMessageAvailable(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_RX_BUFFER0) == 0);

  /* Retrieve message from Rx buffer 0. Rec msg from Node 2 */
  if(HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_RX_BUFFER0, &RxHeader, RxData_From_Node2) != HAL_OK)
  {
      Error_Handler();
  }

      hfdcan1.Instance = FDCAN1;
      hfdcan1.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;
      hfdcan1.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_EXTERNAL_LOOPBACK;
      hfdcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
      hfdcan1.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;
      hfdcan1.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
      hfdcan1.Init.NominalPrescaler = 1;
      hfdcan1.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 13;
      hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 86;
      hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 13;
      hfdcan1.Init.DataPrescaler = 2;
      hfdcan1.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 12;
      hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 12;
      hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 12;
      hfdcan1.Init.MessageRAMOffset = 0;
      hfdcan1.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 1;
      hfdcan1.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0 ;
      hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo0ElmtsNbr = 0;
      hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo0ElmtSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;
      hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo1ElmtsNbr = 0;
      hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo1ElmtSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;
      hfdcan1.Init.RxBuffersNbr = 1;
      hfdcan1.Init.RxBufferSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;
      hfdcan1.Init.TxEventsNbr = 0;
      hfdcan1.Init.TxBuffersNbr = 1;
      hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueElmtsNbr = 32;
      hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
      hfdcan1.Init.TxElmtSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;
      if (HAL_FDCAN_Init(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
```

[image: CAN TX][image: CANH]

Comment: "I also saw messages at CAN TX and there is no any move at CAN H or CAN L" This doesn't sound like a software problem at all. I think it would be best to repost this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but focus on the schematic and oscilloscope pictures. Once we've established that your HW is sound, we can take it from there. But the EE site is generally more suitable for questions like this, since firmware for MCUs is also on-topic there. (Feel free to give me a nudge @Lundin here if you repost it on the EE site and I'll take a look at it. Just make sure to include a simple schematic.)

Comment: Actually one interesting story is there. Normally, LTC2875HDD from Analog devices had been picked and pcb designed for this but as you know chip shortage, they had to change with same pinout tranceiver which is  NXP TJA1462ATK/0Z.

And yes it is better to share there. Thanks !

Comment: At a glance, the former is a 3.3V part and the latter is a 5V part. So I'm sensing a Sherlock Holmes conclusion coming up here... Also the NXP part doesn't support split termination.

Comment: In general, CAN transceivers are _not_ compatible unless you examine supply voltage/logic level voltages and the behavior of pin 8 and pin 5. None of these are standardized, so you can't just pick second source at a whim.

Comment: Here is the designer note : 
At time of production, this chip was not available and it is replaced by NXP TJA1462ATK/0Z which has almost identical pin-out but there is a difference how pins 5  and 8 work.
 
TJA1462ATK/0Z has dual voltage pins and on Board pin 5 is missing IO-voltage reference 3.3V and it must be connected with an extra wire.

There is some circuit for splitt pin but it is connected to 0 ohm but remained empty. So we tied 3v3 to VIO. let me share this in electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yep and also they seem to have missed the crucial detail of the NXP part having a minimum Vcc supply of 4.5V, whereas the LT part uses supply within 3.0V - 3.6V. These aren't compatible in the slightest, so that's your problem there.

Comment: TJA1462ATK/0Z can work both 3v3 and 5V. There are different variant work under different voltage.

Comment: Nothing in the datasheet says that it can work on 3V3 supply or at least I can't find it. Don't confuse supply voltage with logic level voltage.

Comment: Actually I just noticed it is the LT part which is 3 to 5V tolerant.